# Get all of domain's email addresses by a Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

Is it possible to get all domain email addresses (@example.com) to a variable? (the domain is of course connected with Gmail). I was searching and have found just ContactsApp class, which can give contacts from address books, but I need all company's email addresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get user information like this for your entire domain, you need to use the Admin SDK Directory API. You will need to query Google Apps for your domain's users.

```
var optionalArgs = {"customer":"my_customer"},
    response,
    users = []
;
response = AdminDirectory.Users.list(optionalArgs);
users = response.users;
```

This will get you your first page of users, so you may need to create a loop to fetch all of them. You will need to understand the User resource, which is returned for each of your users. Both their primary domain email and their aliases can be found in this resource:

```
var email,
    aliases
;
email = users[0].emails[0]; // if email.primary is true, email.address is the primary domain email for this user
aliases = users[0].aliases; // list of user's alias email addresses
```

More information can be found in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users#resource-representations)

Answer (score 0):

This is the function to get all the users email address list in appscript .

```
function listAllUsers1() {
var pageToken;
var page;
do {
page = AdminDirectory.Users.list({
domain: 'abc.com',
orderBy: 'givenName',
maxResults: 100,
pageToken: pageToken,
});
var users = page.users;
  Logger.log(users);
if (users) {
for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
var user = users[i];
  Logger.log(user);
Logger.log('%s (%s)', user.name.fullName, user.primaryEmail);
}
} else {
Logger.log('No users found.');
}
pageToken = page.nextPageToken;
} while (pageToken);
}
```